# What's the meaning of "financial" here?

Tags: sentence-meaning, interpretation

His motives were purely **financial**.

I know,Financial means —Connected with money

Can I interpreted the sentence as:—

**His intentions were completely connected with money in some ways.**

Comment: No. 'Purely financial' means 'connected only with money and nothing else'. Delete 'in some ways'.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I used the phrase **some ways** to express **In a way not yet known or explained or the speaker don't mentioned particularly**.

Comment: What does that mean? You are not making any sense.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey I mean **how the intentions were related to the money completely the speaker don't said so he used "financial", I think.Why the speaker didn't said about "money" directly,but used the term "financial".**

Comment: *Purely financial* is a euphemism for greed.

Comment: @tim I don't think that is true at all. You can say a *relationship* or an *arrangement* is "purely financial" to mean that there is no sentiment there. Relationships and arrangements are abstract and cannot be greedy in themselves.

Comment: @Astralbee  Yes, but the phrase doesn't refer to an arrangement but to "motives".  If referring to an arrangement, we would refer to "purposes" not "motives". But I'm certainly willing to qualify "is *often* a euphemism..."

Comment: The speaker  doesn't leave anything unsaid. **Purely financial** = only to do with money.

Comment: @KateBunting If the speaker don't use the word "purely", then what will be the interpretation?

Comment: The same, but  without the emphasis on _only_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this means "His motives were only about money." Meaning that the subject of the sentence wasn't motivated by kindness or helping others or family or anything else, only money.

I would expect this sentence to come up in a context where someone is doing something good, but for the wrong reason. So for example, someone chooses to serve on the board of a non-profit organization that cares for children with cancer. But actually, they do this because they can then make the organization buy their company's products, thus giving themself more money. Their motivations would be "purely financial."